# Google map APIv2 работает на Android 5.1, но не работает на 6.0.1

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api

Столкнулся с этой проблемой при компиляции программы на реальном устройстве 6.0.1
На 5.1 (тоже реальное устройство)все работает превосходно, а на 6.0.1 карта просто не отображается. Думаю, что проблема не в коде, хотелось бы узнать причины такого поведения карты. При необходимости могу показать исходники.

**UPDATE:**

```
public class CreateRoom extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener,
        GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener,
        GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener,
        View.OnClickListener,
        com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {

    private static final String STATUS_FAIL = "failed";
    private static final String STATUS_SUCCESS = "success";
    EditText editTextNewRoomTitle;
    SeekBar seekBarRadius;
    TextView textViewRadius;
    GoogleMap mMap;
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    LocationRequest locationRequest;
    User user;
    String room_name;
    String room_id;
    int radius;
    boolean isEdit;
   // private Room room = null;

    private double longitude;
    private double latitude;

    Circle circle;


    LocationManager locationManager;


    public static CreateRoom newInstance() {
        CreateRoom fragment = new CreateRoom();
        fragment.setArguments(new Bundle());
        return fragment;
    }

    public boolean isGoodData() {
        return (!editTextNewRoomTitle.getText().toString().isEmpty() && latitude != 0.0 && longitude != 0.0);
    }

    public void editRoom() {

        int radius = (int) circle.getRadius();

        String URL = "http://";
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        params.put("token", user.getToken());
        params.put("user_id", user.getUser_id());
        params.put("radius", Integer.toString(radius));
        params.put("title", editTextNewRoomTitle.getText().toString());
        params.put("latitude", Double.toString(latitude));
        params.put("longitude", Double.toString(longitude));
        params.put("room_id", room_id);


        client.post(URL, params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                try {

                    Log.i("fg", "edit room: " + response.toString());
                    String status = response.getString("status");
                    if (Objects.equals(status, STATUS_FAIL)) {

                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                        builder.setTitle("Ошибка");
                        builder.setMessage("Не удалось создать комнату!");
                        builder.setCancelable(false);
                        builder.setNegativeButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

                        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                        alertDialog.show();


                    } else if (Objects.equals(status, STATUS_SUCCESS)) {
                        getActivity().finish();
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {

            }

            @Override
            protected Object parseResponse(byte[] responseBody) throws JSONException {
                return super.parseResponse(responseBody);

            }
        });

    }


    public void createNewRoom() {

        int radius = (int) circle.getRadius();

        String URL = "http://";
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        params.put("token", user.getToken());
        params.put("user_id", user.getUser_id());
        params.put("radius", Integer.toString(radius));
        params.put("title", editTextNewRoomTitle.getText().toString());
        params.put("latitude", Double.toString(latitude));
        params.put("longitude", Double.toString(longitude));


        client.post(URL, params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    String status = response.getString("status");
                    if (Objects.equals(status, STATUS_FAIL)) {

                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                        builder.setTitle("Ошибка");
                        builder.setMessage("Не удалось создать комнату!");
                        builder.setCancelable(false);
                        builder.setNegativeButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

                        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                        alertDialog.show();


                    } else if (Objects.equals(status, STATUS_SUCCESS)) {
                        Log.i("fg", "was here");
                        Room room = new Room();
                        JSONArray responseArray = response.getJSONArray("response");
                        for (int i = 0; i < responseArray.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject data = responseArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            room.setTitle(editTextNewRoomTitle.getText().toString());
                            room.setUsersCount("1");
                            room.setRoom_id(data.getString("room_id"));
                            Log.i("fg", "Room id " + room.getRoom_id());
                        }

                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Dialog.class);
                        intent.putExtra("user", user);
                        intent.putExtra("room", room);
                        intent.putExtra("room_id", room.getRoom_id());
                        intent.putExtra("room_name", room.getTitle());
                        intent.putExtra("latitude", latitude);
                        intent.putExtra("longitude", longitude);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        getActivity().finish();


                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {

            }

            @Override
            protected Object parseResponse(byte[] responseBody) throws JSONException {
                return super.parseResponse(responseBody);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        user = getArguments().getParcelable("user");
        room_name = getArguments().getString("room_name");
        room_id = getArguments().getString("room_id");
        radius = getArguments().getInt("radius");
        isEdit = getArguments().getBoolean("isEdit");
        Context context = getActivity();
        locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.create_room, container, false);
        editTextNewRoomTitle = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextNewRoomTitle);
        if(isEdit){
            editTextNewRoomTitle.setText(room_name);
        }
        textViewRadius = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewRadius);
        if(isEdit){
            textViewRadius.setText(Integer.toString(radius) + "м");
        }
        seekBarRadius = (SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.seekBarRadius);
        seekBarRadius.setMax(25000);
        seekBarRadius.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (isEdit) {
                    seekBarRadius.setProgress(radius);
                } else {
                    seekBarRadius.setProgress(3000);
                }
            }
        });

        seekBarRadius.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                if (circle != null) {
                    if (progress == 0) {
                        progress = 1;
                    }
                    textViewRadius.setText(Integer.toString(progress) + "м");
                    circle.setRadius(progress);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                moveMap();
            }
        });

        createLocationRequest();

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Log.i("fg", "onViewCreated");
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.mapToday);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getContext())
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        Log.i("fg", "onStart");
        super.onStart();
        googleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        Log.i("fg", "onMapReady");
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);
        mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        getCurrentLocation();

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {

    }


    private void getCurrentLocation() {

        Log.i("fg", "current loc");

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);

        if (location == null) {
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
        if (location != null) {


            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            latitude = location.getLatitude();

            if (circle == null) {

                circle = mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                        .center(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                        .radius(seekBarRadius.getProgress())
                        .strokeColor(Color.BLACK).fillColor(0x33000000));

// radius

            } else {
                circle.setCenter(new LatLng(latitude, longitude));

            }

            moveMap();

        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        googleApiClient.disconnect();


    }

    private void moveMap() {

        if (latitude != 0.0 && longitude != 0.0) {

            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(getZoomLevel(circle)));
            mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.i("fg", "update");
        getCurrentLocation();

        if (circle != null) {
            circle.setCenter(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())));
        }
        if (circle == null) {

            int radius = 0;
            if (seekBarRadius.getProgress() == 0) {
                radius = 1;
            } else {
                radius = seekBarRadius.getProgress();
            }

            circle = mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                    .center(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                    .radius(radius)
                    .strokeColor(Color.RED));
        }

        moveMap();

        Log.i("fg", Double.toString(latitude) + " " + Double.toString(longitude));

    }

    private void createLocationRequest() {
        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setInterval(5000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(3000);

    }

    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
    }

    public void resetCircle() {
        circle = null;

    }

    public float getZoomLevel(Circle circle) {
        float zoomLevel = 0.0f;
        if (circle != null) {
            double radius = circle.getRadius();
            double scale = radius / 500;
            zoomLevel = (float) (16 - Math.log(scale) / Math.log(2)) - 1.2f;
        }
        return zoomLevel;
    }
}
```

Заранее благодарю за помощь！

Comment: дали ли разрешение приложению отображать Ваше местоположение на карте (для ОС Android 6 и выше)?

Comment: Как это делается?

Comment: Неужели из за этого карта не будет отображаться?

Comment: без исходников все таки не получится ответить четко

Comment: Обновил, в данный момент все выглядит вот так

Comment: +1 к runtime permissions. Для начала можете попробовать дать приложению доступ к GPS вручную (в списке приложения находите Ваше -> разрешения -> и там разрешить доступ к GPS).

Comment: Еще можно логи посмотреть.

Comment: Может ли быть проблема в request permissions? Их в коде нет, потому что ранее я компилил на 5.1

Comment: обязательно нужно!

Comment: Что именно нужно?

Comment: request permissions нужен